# OpenGL obj loader for iOS

Tags: ios, object, opengl-es, 3d

I would like to know if there's an iOS library or framework for loading *.obj in an iOS OpenGL project. I would like something simple (as simp have so compiling problem on Xcode 4.2).

I tried to find something but without success ...

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What library did you use ? Only OpenGL ? Try `cocos2d`

Comment: I would like to use 3D model and video texture, so I don't think that Cocos2d is made for this use.

Comment: don't forget its extension, `cocos3d`.

Comment: Hum indeed ! And am I able to texture an object with a video ?

Comment: not exactly found an answer, but here is what people do : http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/19853

Comment: Check out [this library](https://github.com/vovagalchenko/mishmesh). You can render and interact with your OBJ geometry using it on iOS. Here's a [short video of the library in action](http://youtu.be/ahDldv0AnMc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/). This is great library that understands lots of different formats. It's C and C++ so you can use it with your Objective C code.